# How were Wichita and Little Rock named?

Tags: names, zombieland

In the movie *Zombieland*, the two main male characters are named for where they're trying to get to... to avoid real names and keep from getting "too close": Tallahassee and Columbus.

In short order, they meet Wichita and Little Rock, the two main female characters.

I've been trying to figure out why they were named such tho. It wasn't based on where they were trying to get to, seeing as they were both trying to get to some suburb of Los Angeles (Pacific Playland was located right outside LA). It doesn't seem it'd be where they were coming from, since they were sisters and traveling together, they likely would've come from the same place.

I suppose the two towns are close enough, maybe Wichita was away at college in Wichita, and when the outbreak started, she went home and rescued her sister in Little Rock.

Was wondering though if in the script, or maybe a novelization (does a movie like *Zombieland* *get* novelization?), if it explained their names any further.

Comment: I always figured he named her Little Rock because she was the youngest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could find nothing in the movie.

However, it appears that a [*Zombieland* TV series](http://www.projectcasting.com/casting/zombieland-tv-series-finds-lead-roles-and-is-still-casting-various-roles/) is planned.  According to the script for the planned pilot, the background for Wichita and Little Rock will be elaborated upon:

**On Wichita:**

> We also learn a lot more about Wichita's backstory, including how she ran away from her father after he had her stealing people's Christmas presents - and later, she found out she had a sister who was also being a grifter with her dad.

**and Little Rock:**

> And she share some of her own backstory, about how her dad parked her at school while he went off grifting on his own - and then yanked her out of school right before a dance that she was looking forward to.

While not explicitly mentioning the towns they were respectively living in, it does provide a pretty good reason to suspect that your theory wasn't too far off: Wichita had possibly fled from Little Rock to flee her father, and then returned to rescue her sister.

Comment: Hmm, that could be interesting. Guess it probably wouldn't have the same actors though... which it'd be hard to see anyone but them playing the characters... especially Woody Harrelson. Doubt he wants to go back to TV though.

Comment: The article confirmed that none of the original cast will be returning :(

Comment: Ah, yes... just read it. Shame. They were all great in their roles!